# What would be another way to phrase "the moral of the story is..."?

Tags: phrase-requests

What would be another way to phrase "the moral of the story is..." ?

Answer (score 6):

How about:

> The lesson to be learnt here is...

Answer (score 2):

The point of the story...

The meaning of the story. . .

The purpose of the story .  .  .

Comment: Not bad answers, but it would be a greater benefit if you connected them to the "moral" of the story.